# Getting HTTP-401 error for SSO application using Apache JMeter 3.0

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on, http-status-code-401, www-authenticate, negotiate

I am getting HTTP-401 (Unauthorized) error for single sign-on (SSO) application which I am trying to test. I am passing HTTP Authorization Manager with following information:
Username/Password/Domain/Mechanism(KERBEROS).

I am getting following response headers in "View Results Tree" listener:

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-length: 11785
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 09 Nov 2017 21:55:38 GMT
p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
www-authenticate: Negotiate
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PD-S-SESSION-ID=0_7Yn3C....Ra4+IsxI=; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Can anybody help please?

Thanks,
Krunal

Comment: What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: I tried adding HTTP Authorization Manager as I mentioned above.

Comment: Could you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header has several **directives** which determine [authentication scheme](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml).

[Negotiate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559) value may stand either for [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or for [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) so you need to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your Test Plan and configure it accordingly (you might need to contact your system administrator or application developers to get the correct details).

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more details on bypassing NTLM and/or Kerberos authentication challenges in JMeter tests.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your answer. I already had discussion with developers as well as server resources and I was told it’s not Kerberos. They use TAM WebSeal for authentication, not sure about NTLM. I tried HTTP Authorization Manager but I see 2 auth mechanisms - one is Basic and Digestive and another is Kerberos. If it is not Kerberos then I am left with basic and digestive method. I am not sure if it is NTLM then how would I handle it. Any thoughts?